# dataTable and edit does not work on blade

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, datatables, laravel-blade

I have a Laravel project where I use the plugin dataTable, for rendering a collection of items.

```
    $('#paths').DataTable();
```

So I write some script to allow the user to edit their records, with a modal included on the same page:

```
     $(document).ready(function(e) {
                $(function() {
                $('.editPathButton').on("click", function () {

                    id=$(this).parent().siblings('#path_id').html();
                    nome=$(this).parent().siblings('#path_nome').html();
                    degreeCourses_id=$(this).parent().siblings('#path_degreeCourse_id').val();

                    console.log(id+nome+degreeCourses_id);

                    $('#pathId_edit').val(id);
                    $("#nome_edit").html(nome);
                    $('#degreeCourses_id_edit').val(degreeCourses_id);
                });

});
```

Everything works good (even just the console.log) with the first "page" of the table, but if I choose to see more than the "standard" row, or I switch the page (of the table) the edit script stops to work, but is still on the same HTML page, and the id and class are identical for each record of the table! And the script is still on the DOM

the view:

the table part

```
 <table id="paths" class="table table-responsive table-hover text-center">
                        <thead>
                        <tr class="intestazione">
                            <td>Id</td>
                            <td>Nome</td>
                            <td>Corso di Laurea</td>
                            <td>Edit</td>
                            <td>Delete</td>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        @foreach($paths as $path)
                                <tr>
                                    <td id="path_id">{{$path->id}}</td>
                                    <td id="path_nome">{{$path->nome}}</td>
                                    <td id="path_degreeCourse">{{$path->degreeCourse->nome}}</td>
                <input type="hidden" id="path_degreeCourse_id" value="{{$path->degreeCourse->id}}">


                                    <td>
                                      <button id="edit_path" class="btn btn-warning editPathButton"
                                                    data-toggle="modal"
                                                    data-target="#editPathModal">
                                                <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                                            </button>
                                        </td>

                                </tr>
                        @endforeach
                        </tbody>
</table>
```

the modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="editPathModal"
         tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
         aria-labelledby="favoritesModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close"
                            data-dismiss="modal"
                            aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title"
                        id="editPathModalLabel">Modifica Indirizzo</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    {!! Form::open(['url' => 'admin/lauree', 'method' => 'put']) !!}
                    {{ Form::hidden('pathId_edit','', array('id' => 'pathId_edit')) }}
                    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="name">Nome</label>
                            {{ Form::text('nome_edit', '', array('class' => 'form-control','id'=>'nome_edit')) }}
                            @if($errors->edit_path->has('nome_edit'))
                                @foreach($errors->edit_path->get('nome_edit') as $msg)
                                    <span class="label label-danger error_mex">{{$msg}}</span>
                                @endforeach
                            @endif
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="degreeCourses_id">Corso di Laurea</label>
                            {{ Form::select('degreeCourses_id_edit', $degreeCourses, null, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12 text-right">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Annulla</button>
                    </div>
                    {!! Form::close() !!}
                </div>
```

Comment: `$(function() {` where this ends? Is your code correct?

Comment: @Iftikharuddin yes just errors on paste it... the code seems corretct to me and my browser...

Comment: Could you put a part of the view containing the table?

Comment: @RouhollahMazarei ive update the post as request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found why this, and how to solve it!

the problem is about how is rendered the records and how the "onclick" listener are setted. at the first rendering of the page N record are rendered, and the DOM contains the script that set the listener on each record/button;

when you go to N+1 record the DOM is the same, but the page isnt reloaded so the listerner are not setted again for this and all the rest...

So the easyest solution is to move the listener inside the button, and write a function to call to set the data for the modal.

So the button will be:

```
<button id="edit_path" 
        class="btn btn-warning editPathButton"
        data-toggle="modal"
        onclick="editPath(this)"
        data-target="#editPathModal">
        <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
</button>
```

and the function:

```
 function editPath(el) {
            id=$(el).parent().siblings('#path_id').html();
            nome=$(el).parent().siblings('#path_nome').html();
            degreeCourses_id=$(el).parent().siblings('#path_degreeCourse_id').val();

            console.log(id+nome+degreeCourses_id);



            $('#pathId_edit').val(id);
            $("#nome_edit").val(nome);
            $('#degreeCourses_id_edit').html(degreeCourses_id);     
        }
```